# How do I stop the datepicker from displaying by default if no date is entered

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am using jquery-ui-1.10.4.js and ASP MVC.
In my View I am accepting an optional date as input;

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Assessment.SsipAccreditationDate)
```

I have an Editor Template which injects the datepicker class;

```
 @model DateTime?  
 @Html.TextBox("", (Model.HasValue ? Model.Value.ToLongDateString() : string.Empty), 
    new { @class = "datePicker", @style = "width:200px;" })
```

I have jquery code to hook up the datepicker with the date field;

```
if ($(".datePicker").length) {
    $(".datePicker").datepicker({ showOn: 'both', dateFormat: constantDateFormat, changeMonth: true, changeYear: true })
        .next('button.ui-datepicker-trigger')
        .attr("tabIndex", "-1");
}
```

When the View is loaded, if this date field is empty the datepicker automatically displays. What I would prefer would be for the datepicker to only be displayed if the user clicks on it or the associated button. This is what the showOn: Both configuration is meant to acheive.
Notice in the jquery the tab index is set to -1, so the reason for the datepicker showing cannot be to do with the field in focus.
So how do I stop the datepicker showing when the View is loaded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not think this is the best answer, but I found I could do this by disabling the datepicker initially, and then enabling it once it has been clicked on;

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    initialiseEdit();
});

var initialiseEdit = function () {

    // Disable the datepicker to ensure the datepicker is not shown when the page is loaded
    $('#Assessment_SsipAccreditationDate').datepicker("disable");

    // Class to stop the control from looking disabled
    $('#Assessment_SsipAccreditationDate').addClass('inputBox');
};

// This code is to make the datepicker function as though it is enabled, whether it is or not.
$('.clickEnable').click(function () {
    $('#Assessment_SsipAccreditationDate').datepicker("enable");
    $('#Assessment_SsipAccreditationDate').datepicker("show");
});
```

Because '#Assessment_SsipAccreditationDate' is disabled, I had to wrap it with a span containing the clickEnable class and put the click event on that.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable it by using `defaultDate` attribute.

```
$(".datePicker").datepicker({
        defaultDate: ''
})
```